# How to make tooltip (qtip2) on the top in center? And how to add image inside it?

Tags: jquery, html, css, tooltip, qtip2

Sorry for this question, but how can I make my tooltip(qtip2) appears on the top(center)with tooltip tail and with some picture inside? This is my code:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    <div class="col-xs-3  col-sm-3  col-md-3 col-lg-3 tooltip-item ">
         <div class="wrapper-tooltips test">
             <div class="first-line">
                2 min
             </div>
             <div class="second-line">
                from
             </div>
             <div class="destinations-line">
             <span>square</span>
             </div>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>

    $('.test').qtip({
        content: {
            text: 'My common piece of text here'
        },
        position : {
            my : 'top center',
            at : 'top center'

        }
    })
```

This is what I want to have:  http://take.ms/gIh67

What can you reccomend me to do? Maybe I should take another tooltip plugin, not qtip2? Thank's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the tooltip using css based on your html structure.

html element

```
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
  <div class="col-xs-3  col-sm-3  col-md-3 col-lg-3 tooltip-item ">

        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="first-line">
                2 min
             </div>
             <div class="second-line">
                from
             </div>
             <div class="destinations-line">
             <span>square</span>
             </div>
            <div class="tooltip">
              <span><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/graphicpeel/balloons/512/Small-Twitter-Logo-in-Pink-icon.png">
              </span><span>I am a tooltip!</span>
          </div>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Css

```
.wrapper {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #ececec;
  color: #555;
  cursor: help;
  font-family: "Gill Sans", Impact, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 100px 75px 10px 75px;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0); /* webkit flicker fix */
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; /* webkit text rendering fix */
}

.wrapper .tooltip {
  background: #1496bb;
  bottom: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  left: -25px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(10px);
     -moz-transform: translateY(10px);
      -ms-transform: translateY(10px);
       -o-transform: translateY(10px);
          transform: translateY(10px);
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-out;
     -moz-transition: all .25s ease-out;
      -ms-transition: all .25s ease-out;
       -o-transition: all .25s ease-out;
          transition: all .25s ease-out;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
     -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
      -ms-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
       -o-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
          box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
}

/* This bridges the gap so you can mouse into the tooltip without it disappearing */
.wrapper .tooltip:before {
  bottom: -20px;
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}  

/* CSS Triangles - see Trevor's post */
.wrapper .tooltip:after {
  border-left: solid transparent 10px;
  border-right: solid transparent 10px;
  border-top: solid #1496bb 10px;
  bottom: -10px;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -13px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
}

.tooltip img{
  width: 50px;
}

.tooltip span{
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.wrapper:hover .tooltip {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
     -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
      -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
       -o-transform: translateY(0px);
          transform: translateY(0px);
}

/* IE can just show/hide with no transition */
.lte8 .wrapper .tooltip {
  display: none;
}

.lte8 .wrapper:hover .tooltip {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: thank's, but how can I integrate this into my code? I don't have any <a> elements. Or it is unnecessary? I've tried several times, but nothing worked(

Comment: Plz see the updated answer. I tried to structure it as per your html format.

Comment: thank you so much) You helped me) hope will help you someday too)